Moving Breakers in Electrical Panel to Make Room for Generator Interlock
I am installing a large portable generator and will be adding a 50amp inlet and corresponding breaker in my 125A electrical panel to backfeed during power outages. I purchased this house recently, which was built in 1990, and do not have any legible documentation for the electrical panel.
The dryer is gas so really doesn't pull 30A. Water heater and oven are also gas for reference. Washer, dryer and oven would not be used while the 4 ton AC unit (with easy start equipped) is running on generator power. Tangentially, I have purchased a 3200W inverter to run essential lights and appliances while the AC is off to limit noise pollution and provide cleaner inputs.

In order to free up the slots beneath the 125A main breaker, can I shift "Livingroom" to the bottom right position by removing the spacers around the "Dryer" breaker push everything on the right side up?
If I desired, could I add whole home surge protection to the slot directly to the right of the 125A main breaker? I have read conflicting opinions on whether this area can be utilized.
Is there an obvious way to tell exactly which panel this is so I can be sure I am purchasing the appropriate interlock kit? The documentation on the panel is old and pretty difficult to read.
Anything in this panel that should be redone while doing this? For example, I don't believe I have seen 3 wires terminate into a single hole in a bus bar as seen on the right side of my panel.





You have bigger problems than moving breakers.  Challenger breakers and panels are not safe and should be replaced.

How are you running a (presumably 120V) gas dryer off a pair of 30A breakers with no Neutral in the cable ... ? Please tell me that you don't have a 15/20A outlet on the end of one Hot wire and you're using the bare ground as Neutral ...

Thanks for the feedback. Brhans, I inherited this panel and hadn't looked into this before now - this does seem to be the case. Combined with the other feedback from crip and manassehkatz it would appear it's time I call out a licensed electrician.

Read the limited scope of actual recall of gfci breakers here https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/1988/challenger-electrical-equipment-corp-offers-replacement-program-for-9000-gfci-circuit

With most high amp stuff being gas, you probably do not need to upgrade your electric system to 200 amps.  That does not mean you cannot use a nice big 200 amp panel(good cost per buck), limited to 125 amps.  Electric heating/tankless water heaters(not usually a good choice for most people) will need a system upgrade in the future.

The panel label is hard to read. But I can read enough to see CHALLENGER. Challenger breakers are considered a major fire hazard. In addition, you have a very small panel by modern standards - 16 spaces assuming all spaces can be used, compared to a typical new panel between 30 and 42 spaces. You have a bunch of half-size ("tandem"/"double-stuff") breakers, and without those you would already have run out of space, but those are problematic for a bunch of reasons, including:

30A dryer double breaker straddles two spaces because it has to, resulting in empty half-spaces and no net savings.
For most panels GFCI (there are some exceptions) and AFCI are not available in half-size breakers.

Easy to say because it isn't my money, but I recommend doing what I did a couple of years ago - entirely replace the old panel (in my case it was 1 small breaker panel and 2 very old fuse boxes) with a modern new 30-space (not "circuit") or larger, 200A panel. That will:

Allow you to put in a proper interlock for the generator
Get you out of Challenger problems - which are a real safety concern
Provide space for a surge protector
Provide space for future expansion, including GFCI and/or AFCI breakers where needed. Newer code requires AFCI for many circuits (practically speaking, that almost always means "AFCI/breaker") and now GFCI even for 240V circuits (120V circuits can be easily handled with "GFCI/receptacle" but for 240V you need "GFCI/breaker").

FYI, 3 ground wires (not neutral wires) is allowed in a single screw position in some panels for some ground wire sizes. But that's kind of irrelevant compared to the bigger issues here.

Thank you, I was already looking to upgrade to a larger 200A panel eventually and this Challenger concerns is the feedback I needed to go ahead and do that sooner rather than later.
